# I need to create a Javascript Function to create custom push function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building JavaScript code to make a custom push function. My new function should act exactly like the original push function.

Here is the code. Please check it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function MyArray(){
    this.add=function(x){

        return this[this.length]=x;
    }
}

MyArray.prototype=Array.prototype;

var collection = new MyArray();


collection.push(44);

collection.add(56); // this is not working. 

collection.push(77);
collection.push(88);

console.log(collection);

</script>
```

Comment: You can't really subclass arrays in ES5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're not using a native array, the `length` property doesn't automatically adjust itself. You need to increment it manually, otherwise the next `push` will just overwrite it:

```
function MyArray(){
    this.add=function(x){

        return this[this.length++]=x;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I pass a set of array element as argument in my function to append whit my current array. Its not working. can you please check.

Comment: Is I need to add as a new questing ?

Comment: Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have another problem.

Comment: please check this questing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469074/custom-array-function-using-prototype-new-myarray1-2-3-4-not-working

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `add` instead of `push` (so, use `add` as `push`-alias), just refer to the original `Array.prototype.push`. See snippet. The snippet also contains a custom `addMulti` method, derived from `Array.prototype.push`.

```js
function MyArray(){ }
MyArray.prototype = Array.prototype;
MyArray.prototype.add = Array.prototype.push;

// custom addMulti method, derived from Array.prototype.push
MyArray.prototype.addMulti = function addMulti(arrayOfValues){
    [].push.apply(this, arrayOfValues);
};

var foo = new MyArray;
// add and push both work
foo.add(13);
foo.push(17);
foo.add(15,16,18);
foo.push(112);
// push an array of values
foo.addMulti([200,300,400,500]);

var report = new MyArray;
report.add('<code>foo.length: ',foo.length, ', foo: [', foo, ']</code>');
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = report.join('');
```

```html
<div id="result"><div>
```