# Custom array Function using prototype. new MyArray(1,2,3,4) not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

All I need is a custom function to act as an native Array object. When I create an object it should act like same as the `new Array(1,2,3,4)`. It should create an array of elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function MyArray(){

}

MyArray.prototype=Array.prototype;

var collection = new MyArray(1, 2, 3, 4);


console.log(collection);


// My code should act like. 

var coll= new Array(1,2,3,4);

console.log(coll);

</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need `a custom function to act as an native Array object`?

Comment: Looks like you wanted to subclass Array. Not a [simple task](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/).

Comment: Subclass array is that the solution.

Comment: You can't create a true subclass of Array, because only Array instances have the special *length* property. If you want to emulate the Array constructor, you'll need to give it internal methods so it behaves like the real [*Array* constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2). But you can't emulate the length property.

Comment: HI can you please check that i have answered my questing. And is it the right way to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize a `MyArray` instance by checking the arguments in the constructor and push them if applicable. You may ask yourself if you really need a custom `MyArray` constructor to mimic `Array`. When you need custom methods, extending the `Array.prototype` may be a better option. The enclosed snippet demonstrates this too.

```js
function MyArray() { 
  if (arguments.length) {
    [].push.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
MyArray.prototype = new Array;

var resultdiv = document.querySelector('#result');


// create new instance of MyArray
var foo = new MyArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

// downside: you can't do this
foo[foo.length] = 7;

// use MyArray for reporting
var report = new MyArray('<code>foo length: ', 
                          foo.length,
                         ', foo: [',
                          foo, 
                         ']<br><b>@abforce</b>: ',
                         'foo.hasOwnProperty(\'length\') =&gt; ',
                          foo.hasOwnProperty('length'),
                         '</code>');

resultdiv.innerHTML = report.join('');

// alternative: adding custom methods to Array.prototype
Array.prototype.lastItem = function () {
  return this[this.length-1];
};

var bar = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

// now you can
bar[bar.length] = 7;

resultdiv.innerHTML += ['<br><code>bar last item: ',
                        bar.lastItem(),
                       '</code>'].join('');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Notice that `length` still doesn't work well. Try to add the line `foo[6] = 7;` after your instantiation. (`foo.push(7)` would work, as it manually updates `.length`)

Comment: @Bergi: yep, that's the downside of it. Maybe it's better to point OP to the possibility to extend the `Array.prototype` with custom methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can return an instance of an array in your constructor function

```
function MyArray(){
    return new Array();
}
```

Note that in this situation, because your constructor function *explicitly* returns an object, hence the implicit returning of *this* [will be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this).

But in this case the returned object does *not* follow the `MyArray.prototype`, it will be linked to `Array.prototype` instead.

Comment: @Explore-X As other members already have stated, you cannot create your own subclass of `Array` and my code does not provide a pattern, in which you can implement such structure. It just tell you, you can return objects from your constructor to overriding implicit returning of *this*

Comment: HI can you please check that i have answered my questing. And is it the right way to do.

Comment: Well, if your function returns a new `Array`, then it's no longer a *constructor* function.

Answer (score 0):

Its working.

```
function MyArray() {
  var arr = [ ];
  arr.push.apply(arr, arguments);
  arr.__proto__ = MyArray.prototype;
  return arr;
}

MyArray.prototype = new Array;

// Add custom functions here to MyArray.prototype.
MyArray.prototype.last = function() {
  return this[this.length - 1];
};

var sub = new MyArray(1, 2, 3);


console.log(sub);
</script>
```

Comment: You should use `MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)` instead.